# Place search bar in navigation using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a site using Bootstrap. I have one header, which includes the sites logo, I then want on the right of the container a search bar, aligned vertically in the header. My second header then has my link navigation stretching across the container.

I am having trouble adding the search bar, I tried to add it into a ul and pull to the right but it just went below my logo and full width.

Here is a bootsnip

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/d393M

The mark up i am using for my search is

```
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-info" type="button">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link to the Bootsnip is not working so I can't look at it in more depth.

Try wrapping the search inside form tags as follows (this code from getbootstrap.com):

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: When you wrote "I am having trouble adding the search bar" do you mean to say "navigation links" instead of "search bar"? IOW, are you trying to get the navigation links to appear to the right underneath the search box? If not, draw a mockup of what you are trying to achieve using something like gomockingbird.com so it is clear what you are aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding your form in a `form` element and adding the `.navbar-form` class to it.